# Decrementing Field Size and dequeue() method

Tags: java, queue, computer-science

I am trying to work with an array-like queue(circlequeue) and trying to dequeue the first element. Here is my implementation, however, it does not decrements the size variable correctly where it removes the last object. Why is this happening?

```
public Bottle dequeue() throws NoSuchElementException {
    if (isEmpty() || front == -1) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("queue is empty");
}
Bottle tempt = bottles\[front\];
if (front == back) { // when there is only one element in the queue
    front = -1;
    back = -1;
    return tempt;
}
if (front == size - 1) { // when front is the end of the array, set it to first index
    front = 0;
} else if (back == 0) {
    front = back;
} else { // when front is not the end of the array nor
    front = (front) % bottles.length;
}
bottles\[front\] = null;
return tempt;
}
```

when I tried to add "size--;" after all the if and else statement it removes my last element.

Comment: Your code really doesn't make much sense.  You have three variables "front", "back", and "size", but it's not clear what the relationship between them is, or why you need more than two of them.  Write an invariant about the relationship between these variables, and what this means about which elements of the array are in the queue.  For example, why, if back == 0, do you set front = 0?  This makes no sense in a circular queue.  I think you're best off starting over and paying attention to the definition of your queue.